# How to retrive rootViewController embeded in NavigationViewController?

Tags: swift

I had a View Controller as first ViewController of a TabBar and everything worked fine when I had to call it from App Delegate.

```
let homeVC = ((window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).viewControllers![0]) as! GardenViewController
```

Now I added a NavigationController but I don't know how to access to my viewController (GardenViewController) anymore.
I tried everything but nothing seems to work.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let navigationVC = ((window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).viewControllers![0]) as! UINavigationController
let homeVC = navigationVC.viewControllers[0] as! GardenViewController
```